# remove element in jquery then append a new element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove an span element from HTML then replace that element with a new span element.

View the fiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/DCJ9X/

```
<div id="foo">
    <span>FadeOut</span>
</div>

<input id="go" type="button" value="lets go!" />

$('#go').click(function() {

    $('#foo span').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).remove().parent().append('<span>FadeIn</span>').fadeIn(500);
    });

});
```

As always I am grateful for your help stack!

Comment: you can use the replaceWith method. :) http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) instead:

```
    var $span = $('<span>FadeIn</span>');
    $(this).replaceWith($span);
    $span.fadeIn(500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DCJ9X/4/

Or on one line:

```
$(this).replaceWidth($('<span>FadeIn</span>').fadeIn(500));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#foo span').fadeOut(500).replaceWith('<span>FadeIn</span>').hide().fadein(500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if'n you wanted to keep more or less what you have, this works:

```
$('#go').click(function() {

    var $foo = $('#foo');
    $foo.find('span').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $foo.remove('span').append('<span>FadeIn</span>').fadeIn(500);
    });

});
```